# XML/A not connecting to Jaspersoft

Tags: iis-7, jasper-reports, sql-server-2012, ireport, xmla

I setup my XML/A connection using [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx). I can connect to it through remote machines via SSRS and MS-Excel.
But when I am trying to create a XML/A connection in Jaspersoft Studio or iReport, It doesnt show the cubes at all. I am using SQL Server 2012 Enterprise, IIS 7, Jaspersoft Studio 5.2.0 and iReport 5.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I need more detail information but I don't have this problem, I think it's depend to user permission.

Comment: Hi, did you follow the same link or any other one? Is your environment same as mine?